# Modx assign default date to template variable

Tags: modx

I have a template variable of input type date but I'd like to have a default value of the current date at the time the document was first saved.

I've noticed that using the date formatter widget gives an option to "If no value, use current date" however it seems to use the date at the time it is being viewed rather than the date at the time the document was created.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to get the date when the article was saved for the first time is to use [ * createdon * ]

If there is a way to add the created date to a TV, I am not sure. I think your best shot would be to see if you have an event that you could "hook" you Template Variable, and then use the createdon variable everytime the article is saved! I am not sure this works, but This could be a possible!